# Q: How to run single test in multiple devices?

Tags: android, testing, parallel-processing

I tried to look around about how to launch an automated test in multiple devices, but I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

I have like 5 tests per class and I want to execute just one test in all my connected devices, like a End to End test to login.

I tried to use connected device but it doesn't launch only the test I want...

I'm using Espresso, UIAutomator, Gradle and AndroidStudio.

How can I run that single test in my devices using these tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gradle `connectedCheck` command
You can find an example app here from google

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint

There you can also read how to run the example tests on multiple devices from the command line / terminal, or from within Android Studio

You can also take a look at Spoon if you want to use an external tool plugin:
https://github.com/square/spoon

good luck

Comment: I can't use spoon because it doesn't support webview... Also I have several environments in the app so when I use connected check it not just run ALL my tests but also run in all my environments... The github page does not have info about single class or test in multiple devices, at least I didn't found it...

Comment: why not run them from within AndroidStudio? right click on the test class, when you get the popup dialog to choose devices, select all the devices you want, then click OK.

Comment: because I use automated tests that are debugged, and Android Studio don't run on multiple devices if its debug, in that case I need to run on each device at a time.